# ... es zur Handlung des Hauptsatzes kommt

Tags: pronoun, gender

In the following definition of "indem," what does "es" refer to?

> verwendet, um einen Nebensatz einzuleiten, der ausdrückt, wie **es** zur Handlung des Hauptsatzes kommt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Es kommt zu [einer Sache]" is an idiom that means that [a thing] comes about or happens.

"Es" has no real own meaning here, much like in "es regnet" (it rains).

> Am Sonntag kommt es vereinzelt zu Regenschauern.
> Wie ist es dazu gekommen, dass ihr zusammen Urlaub gemacht habt?

Comment: Thank you. Is the idiom listed in the dictionary?

Comment: @Apollyon yes, e.g. number 8 in DWDS "kommen". https://www.dwds.de/wb/kommen#d-1-8

Answer (score 1):

This is just an impersonal "es" like the one in "es regnet".

This meaning of "kommen" is IMHO the one in [definition 11](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommen) in duden.de ("[langsam herankommend] eintreten, sich ereignen").

Comment: What does "zur Handlung des Hauptsatzes kommt" mean?